# Fixed Headers in a DataTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I have a apex:datatable that I am using and I have implemented apex:facets as the headers for each column. I am attempting to allow scrolling for this particular table however I do not want the header to scroll with it. I have searched extensively online and cannot seem to find a solution to this issue.

CSS:

```
 <style>
    .headerFormat {height:30px; position:relative;}
</style>
```

I have tried many things in this CSS (i.e., different position values, top:0px, overflow:hidden). Nothing seems to be doing the trick.

Visualforce Code:

```
 <div id="id" style="overflow:auto; height:500px;">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!myRows}" var="row" headerClass="headerFormat">
        <apex:column style="width:10%">
            <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!myAction}">
                <apex:param name="myParam" assignTo="{!theParam}" value="0"/>
                 THE HEADER CONTENT
            </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!myOutput}"/>
        </apex:column>
            .
            .
            .
     </apex:dataTable>
 </div>
```

I've tried a number of things here as well (i.e., wrapping the whole facet in a div and the "body" in a separate div). Does anyone have a solution to this issue? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need some JavaScript to make this happen. Google has plenty of examples of this in jquery (http://programmingdrunk.com/floatThead/), Google Code (https://code.google.com/p/js-floating-table-headers/), and so on.

Comment: Take a look into this : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/how-do-i-support-scrolling-and-lock-freeze-the-header-row-of-a-pageblocktable/13471#13471 I tried to do this using jquery and VF mash up, may be this can be further modified as you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended just breaking the headers out of the facet and put them in their own div. Therefore, I had a div for just the headers that did not scroll and a scrollable table div.

Comment: can you give an example of this